# Image memory consumption if the image is transparent

Tags: ios, xcode, memory-management, uiimage

I want to start using some background images in my app screen to give some patterns to my app background. Because the image would be full screen I am having my reservations in terms of doing that given the memory consumption.

What I wonder if I use a full background image that is mainly transparent and adds some patters here and there, would that consume as much memory as a full background image that has no transparency in most of its parts given that memory consuptions measurement is `width x height x 4 = bytes in memory` ??

Comment: Yes, if you are worried about that (how many bg do you have?) you draw   with the help of some tools like http://www.paintcodeapp.com/

Comment: It would only be 1 background image. but then you have a few button images. paiintcode or any draw code would consume as much memory once converted to UIImage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The memory consumption will be exactly the same.  That is the nature of bitmaps.